# Prove or disprove: A non-constant non-decreasing polynomial is strictly increasing.

Tags: polynomials, monotone-functions

**Prove or disprove**: **A non-decreasing polynomial is strictly increasing or a constant.**

I feel the above property is true and it should be easy to prove, but I'm not sure how. Let $P(x)$ be the polynomial and suppose that $x_1 < x_2 \land P(x_1) = P(x_2)$. Then as $P$ is non-decreasing, we have $P$ is constant on $[x_1, x_2]$. Now how this contradicts the degree requirements of $P$, I can't formally show.

Comment: How many roots (at most ) can a polynomial of degree $d>0$ have?  How many real numbers are there between $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: Consider the derivative.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't think that works. lulu Ah so, $P(x) = P(x_1)$ gives a contradiction via the number of solutions satisfying it, thnx!

Comment: The derivative is non negative and either zero everywhere or zero at a finite number of points. In the first case the function is constant, in the second it is strictly increasing.

Comment: How do you get the first property?

Comment: That is a property of polynomials.

Comment: Non decreasing implies that the derivative is non negative.

Comment: @copper.hat But that doesnt imply that it is either zero everywhere or zero at a finite number of points.

Comment: How many zeroes can a polynomial have?

Comment: Yes, but this is a roundabout version of @lulu version

Comment: If $p(b)=p(a)$ for some $a<b$ then $\int_a^b p'(x)dx = 0$ and since $p'(x) \ge 0$, this implies that $p'(x) = 0$ for $x \in [a,b]$ and so $p$ is constant.

Comment: @Kaind "*how this contradicts the degree requirements*" $\;-\;$ It means that $\,P(x) - P(x_1)=0\,$ for all $\,x \in [x_1,x_2]\,$. Ask yourself what degree could $\,P(x) - P(x_1)\,$ possibly have.